# How to authenticate webservice request?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, authentication, webforms, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net webforms solution that uses Identity for authentication. Within the solution I have some webservices that handle ajax requests for the site. The controller apis require authentication, which is not a problem from within the solution, since they receive auth cookie from the session. (Or atleast that's how I understood it).
**Question is** how do I handle authentication when calling the webservice outside the solution, for example from an android app or an outside web page etc?
The calling user should be authenticated, so that only user-relevant data can be accessed.

Comment: Let the user provide credentials in your app, create a WebAPI call to login, store the cookie/token?

Comment: Aren't the requests for WebAPI sent as plain text? So would it be safe to do so, or should the credentials be encrypted on the app and then decrypted on the WebAPI? Also can I pass the cookie/token as an object to the app that's just bounced around without the android app knowing anything about it?